# Memory not destroyed completely - memory leak

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm using 2D arrays in my code and I'd like to have same amount of used memory by an app before using `fun`, and after using it. But unfortunately those values are not the same. When I check used memory on the beginning of the `fun` (from code - using `/proc/self/statm`, where OS is linux) it's some amount, and when I check used memory before `return ...` in the `fun` function it's not the same amount as before. Can you see some memory leaks? I think all memory is destroying when not necessary, but maybe there is something wrong with:`actualVertices = newVertices;`. What do you think?

EDIT:
First checking - after creating Independentsets, second checking before return, so Independentsets is not a problem. Beside this Independentsets is deleted after in Main. Problem is in memory for acrualvertices and newVertices

EDIT 2:
Maybe memory checking like that:

```
double getUsedMemory()
{
    int tSize = 0, resident = 0, share = 0;
    ifstream buffer("/proc/self/statm");
    buffer >> tSize >> resident >> share;
    buffer.close();

    return  (double)(resident - share) / ToMBfromB * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
}
```

is a problem? Do you know better ways to make memory statistics programmatically?

```
int** CreateVertices(int row, int col) // Creating 2D array
{
    int** nVertices = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        nVertices[i] = new int[col]();

    return nVertices;
}

void DeleteVertices(int** tab, int rowCount) // Detroying 2D array
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
        delete[] tab[i];

    delete[] tab;
}

int* fun(..., int n)
{
    int* independentSets;
    int** actualVertices;
    int** newVertices;

    int actualVerticesRowCount = n;
    int actualVerticesColCount = 1;

    independentSets = new int[1 << n] ();
    // first memory checking 
    actualVertices = CreateVertices(n, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        independentSets[1 << i] = 1;
        actualVertices[i][0] = i;
    }

    for (int el = 1; el < n; el++)
    {
        int col = el + 1;
        int row = Combination_n_of_k(n, col);

        newVertices = CreateVertices(row, col);
        int l = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < actualVerticesRowCount; ++i)
        {

            // some computations...

            for (int j = actualVertices[i][actualVerticesColCount - 1] + 1; j < n; ++j)
            {   

                // some computations...

                for (int k = 0; k < el; ++k)
                    newVertices[l][k] = actualVertices[i][k];

                newVertices[l][el] = j;

                l++;
            }
        }

        DeleteVertices(actualVertices, actualVerticesRowCount);

        if (el != n - 1)
            actualVertices = newVertices;

        actualVerticesRowCount = row;
        actualVerticesColCount = col;
    }

    DeleteVertices(newVertices, actualVerticesRowCount);
    // second memory checking 
    return independentSets;
}
```

Comment: Memory is being allocated for 'independentSets' and it is not freed

Comment: `independentSets` is being allocated on Heap and doesn't get released by fun() because it is the return value. How do you expect same amount of used-memory by an app before using `fun` and after it? or did I miss something?

Comment: If the array is not mandatory consider this as a replacement for your 2d arrays and the CreateVertices call `std::vector<std::vector<int>> actualVertices(row, std::vector<int>(col));`

Comment: On second thought, only do the above if your compiler supports c++11 or better and std::move. Otherwise `actualVertices = newVertices;` is a back breaker for performance. No clue what compiler comes stock with Ubuntu 12.04, but it is recent enough to be worth trying.

Comment: Unfortunately, my compiler doesn't support c++11.

Comment: @KamilZ: That does not matter. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` returned by value will kick in RVO or NRVO optimization will cause the 2D array to be built in place not copied back. Also it will work with no memory management hassle from you first time (which is already quicker than a non working version using pointers). Try it first. If after testing it is not quick enough then look at optimization.

Comment: I've tried using 2d vectors. Creating vector: `newVertices.assign(row, vector<int>(col));`, deleting: `newVertices.clear();`. Rest of the code is the same. Computation's time lasts about 64% longer when using vectors. Also it consumer about 20% more memory and it didn't release it after finishing computation. So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would use valgrind and run that against anything you suspect has memory leaks.  Using statm (or top, etc) is not the best way to tell that a program is leaking -- it can tell you the program size is increasing, but this doesn't necessarily need to be due to a leak.  For example, allocation patterns can cause fragmentation in the heap which may potentially force the allocator to grow the heap to acquire large enough contiguous spans to contain a requested allocation.  I'm not saying this is the case in your sample, but it's just one of many reasons not to use statm to conclude there's a memory problem.

Succinctly, valgrind is the tool to find leaks; use it.

Comment: I'll consider using it, but is it a built-in tool (Ubuntu 12.04)? Cause I don't have privilages to install anything (student's server). Also I have to get some memory statistics from code that is why I'm using it. Have you better idea to get memory statistics from code?

Comment: Actually I'm not able to install valgrind - I've checked it.

Comment: @KamilZ badger your administrator to install it. Valgrind is an invaluable tool. It is to tracking memory errors what a debugger is to tracking logic errors. Teaching software and not teaching the tools to write good software is... not logical.

Comment: I'll try on my pc later, admin is on his holiday.